# Delaying 8 Seconds not working?

Tags: java, wait

So, I am trying to send a packet (With Spigot) every 8 seconds.
I would post this on the Spigot forums but I always get the error on the wait. I have tried Scheduler but no luck.
Code:

```
Object obj = new Object();
            try {
                synchronized (obj) {
                    while (true) {
                        for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                            System.out.println("Hi");
                            obj.wait(8000);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            }
```

Ignore the Player player thing it does nothing.
Help please. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a `Timer`...

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `wait`?

Comment: Include the error. I'm guessing what you posted doesn't represent what generated the error. If you just want a delay use Thread.sleep instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait()` is a method intended for asynchronous programming, where you let a chunk of code run while something else "needs time" to finish, as to not block the whole execution of the program. Think of it as a a mechanism that lets asynchronous things happen. As per the docs:

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.

Whereas `sleep()` is a method that makes the current thread stand by for a moment until the desired time has passed and so it will continue its execution:

> Thread.sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution for a
>   specified period.

The former is useful in asynchronous programming, where you know something will potentially block execution of your program for a while and you want to do other stuff in that time, like connecting to a socket, probably all in the same thread. The latter is when you want to stop everything from happening for a moment on the same thread.

If what you want to do is just delay the execution of your method, then this would be the way to go:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            System.out.println("Hi");
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        }
    }
} catch (InterruptedException exception) {
    // Catch something here
}
```